# How can I change the package when using sdo-compiler of Eclipse MOXy

Tags: eclipse, moxy

I'm trying to use sdo-compiler to generate Java classes for an XSD. I want to change the package name from the generated one (`org.oasis_open.docs.tosca.ns._2011._12`) to `com.example`.

The schema is available at http://docs.oasis-open.org/tosca/TOSCA/v1.0/cos01/schemas/TOSCA-v1.0.xsd.

I'm calling [sdo-compiler](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/SDO/Compiler) with

```
%ECLIPSELINK_HOME%\bin\sdo-compiler -sourceFile src/main/resources/TOSCA-v1.0-cos01.xsd -targetDirectory target/generated-sources/
```

How can I instruct sdo-compiler to use a different package?

Answer (score 0):

You need to annotate the XML schema to specify an alternate package name.  Below is an example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/schema" 
    xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/schema" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:sdoj="commonj.sdo/java"
    sdoj:package="foo.bar">
</schema>
```

Comment: What if I don't want to change the XSD as the XSD is from OASIS or OMG?